# format 01-01-16 7:43 string to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have the following strings that I'd like to convert to datetime objects:

```
'01-01-16 7:43'
'01-01-16 3:24'
```

However, when I try to use strptime it always results in a does not match format error.

`Pandas to_datetime function` nicely handles the automatic conversion, but I'd like to solve it with the `datetime` library as well.

```
format_ = '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M'

my_date = datetime.strptime("01-01-16 4:51", format_)
```

> ValueError: time data '01-01-16 4:51' does not match format **'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M'**

Answer (score 3):

as i see your date time string `'01-01-16 7:43'`

> its a **`2-digit year`** not  **`4-digit year`**

that in order to parse through a `2-digit year`, e.g. `'16'` rather than `'2016'`, a `%y` is required instead of a `%Y`.

> you can do that like this

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_str = '01-01-16 7:43' 
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%m-%d-%y %H:%M')    
print(type(datetime_object))
print(datetime_object)
```

> give you output **`2016-01-01 07:43:00`**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to match `2016` you should write `%Y` while for `16` you should write `%y`.

That means you should write:

```py
format_ = '%m-%d-%y %H:%M'
```

Check [this link for all format codes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).